# Find all animated gif files in a directory and its subdirectories

Tags: linux, files, gif

let's say that i've done a find for `.gif` files and got a bunch of files back.  I now want to test them to see if they are **animated** gifs.  Can i do this via the command line?

I have uploaded a couple of examples in the following, in case you want to experiment on them.

#### Animated GIF image

[image: animated gif image]

#### Static GIF Image

[image: static gif image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can easily be done using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

```
identify -format '%n %i\n' -- *.gif

12 animated.gif
1 non_animated.gif
```

`identify -format %n` prints the number of frames in the gif; for animated gifs, this number is bigger than 1.

(ImageMagick is probably readily available in your distro's repositories for an easy install)

Comment: Perfect, thanks - i have ImageMagick installed already.

Answer (score 10):

Using `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -q -if '$framecount > 1' -p '$directory/$filename' -r -ext:gif .
```

Would report the paths of the GIF files that have more than one frame (in the current directory, recursively).

Answer (score 5):

Another way with `im` using the [`fx`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php) operator:

```
find . -type f -name \*.gif -exec sh -c \
'identify -format "%[fx:n>1]\n" "$0" | grep -q 1' {} \; -print
```

This searches the current directory and its subdirectories for `.gif` images running that shell command for each `.gif` found. If number of frames `n>1` then `fx` prints `1`, otherwise it prints `0`. This is piped to `grep -q 1` so `-print` is only executed if the previous `-exec` was successful.