# Identify (and delete) all .gif files with more than 1 frame in all subdirectories

Tags: scripting, imagemagick, gif

I having the following linux command to identify all .gif files and list its frames in the active directory:

```
identify -format '%n %i\n' -- *.gif
```

Now I want to modify and expand the command to fullfil the following:

1. indentify just the .gif files with MORE than 1 frame
2. look also in all subdirectories (right now the command is just looking at the active directory)
3. a command to:
   a) list the identified files
   b) delete the identified files (more important)

Comment: _"I having the following linux command..."_ If you go back there and scroll down: [`find . -type f -name \*.gif -exec sh -c \
'identify -format "%[fx:n>1]\n" "$0" | grep -q 1' {} \; -print -delete`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224631)

Comment: @don_crissti awesome!! this did the job!! thank you a lot for yor help!!! very much appreciated!